# Get Process object by window in WASP/powershell?

Tags: powershell, wasp

I have a function which makes  a window -a TOPMOST window.

So - I can run this :

`Get-WindowByProcessTitle *chrome* | Set-TopMost`

Notice the argument here is a process name  ( `"chrome"` is in `"chrome.exe"` which is the process).

The inner code which  finally selects the process is :

```
Get-Process |  Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "*chrome*"} | Select-Object Id,Name,MainWindowHandle,MainWindowTitle
```

Great.

**Question**

Now I have a query which select a `window` according to its `title` :

```
Select-Window *chrome* |  Where {$_.Title  -like "*$WindowTitle*"} | Select-Object -first 1
```

Which yields :

```
ProcessName : chrome
ProcessId   : 3972
IsActive    : False
Handle      : 1641684
Title       : Watch Full movie The Beach (2000) Online Free | FFilms.org - Google Chrome
Class       : Chrome_WidgetWin_1
```

How can I get the process **object**  ( not the ProcessId) from this query of mine ?

I think I need something like : (psuedo)

```
Select-Window *chrome* |  Where {$_.Title  -like "*$WindowTitle*"} |What_Is_MyProcess_Object? |Select-Object Id,Name,MainWindowHandle,MainWindowTitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walid's answer is valid but it will return object with a processes matching `ProcessName`. You are looking for a match with a single `processId`

If you don't need the other data you could just select the ProcessID

From your code snippet:

```
Select-Window *Online video* |  Where {$_.Title  -like "*$WindowTitle*"} | Select-Object -first 1
```

Just put that code right in a Get-Process call.

```
Get-Process -Pid (Select-Window *Online video* |  Where {$_.Title  -like "*$WindowTitle*"} | Select-Object -first 1 ).ProcessID
```

This will expand the process ID from your code and put it into the `-pid` of a get-process cmdlet. 
A more elegant solution might be this

```
$processToLocate = Select-Window *Online video* |  Where {$_.Title  -like "*$WindowTitle*"} | Select-Object -first 1 -ExpandProperty ProcessID
Get-Process -Pid $processToLocate
```

This should do the same thing. Just might be easier to read. Just uses `-ExpandProperty` instead of `(Object).Property`. The same goal is accomplished in both cases.

**Or**

Walid's suggestion from the comments would also work

```
Select-Window *Online video* |  Where {$_.Title  -like "*$WindowTitle*"} | Select-Object -first 1  | Get-Process -PID {$_.ProcessID}
```

Always though that would could only use `$_` in something like a foreach. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You have a space in `Select-Window *Online *` remove the space like in your example `Select-Window *Online*` or `Select-Window *Online Video*`. It thinks the lone `*` asterisk is a separate argument which it is not, hence the error you got.

Comment: @Matt: thanks for sharing..could you please test if delayed bind scriptblock work for you: select-window...| where...| select -first 1 | get-process -pid { $_.processId}

Comment: @walidtoumi Yes that does work and keeps the code as a single line. Updated the answer with your comment. You should change your answer to your comment. That is the easiest answer I think.

Comment: @Matt: +1 for testing

Comment: Great. for those who wants ( to make a window- top most via a substring of its title)  : http://jsbin.com/vewoco/2/edit
notice. this codes searches only for dynamic names in the **chrome** process. ( chrome is not a part of params). I just dont know how to send 2 params :-)... ps all the remarks are remarks of older code which selects via process name and not via window

Comment: ( for those who ask why ?  - well it's nice to see video in a 300x300 chrome - while programming.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if work:

```
....$WindowTitle*"} | get-process |Select-Object ..
```